# How a SpringBoot service in Kubernetes cluster knows about counter services address changing?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, configmap

I have bunch of applications in a Kubernetes cluster, they connect to each other, like SpringBoot application connect to RabbitMQ. They all are in containers.

Usually standalone SpringBoot app reads configs from application.yaml/bootstrap.yaml but AFAIK in case of Kubernetes cluster it reads it from ConfigMap, and address of counter services should be stored there ( is it?)

So the question is: in case of RabbitMQ pod's redeploy ( e.g. fail and restart) how SpringBoot is triggered to reread new configs? Who triggers it? When?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring cloud kubernetes](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-kubernetes) has [proertysource reload](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.0.0.M2/multi/multi__propertysource_reload.html) feature and is able to trigger an application reload when a related ConfigMap or Secret changes. So if rabbitmq endpoint changes you can update the configMap and application will reload automatically and pick up the new config. But in a real production scenario you will have a stable endpoint for rabbitmq exposed via kubernetes [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Even though pod IPs may change the service IP or DNS will remain same.

The rabbitmq should be deployed as [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) providing table, unique network identifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So Why do you think propertysource reload feature is not for prod scenaro? Is it because anyway kubernetes provide it?

Comment: Well I am saying you should not use it if needed..but I am saying you will mostly will not need it for stuff like rabbitmq endpoints

Comment: ah, ok got it, and what is propertysource reload feature is most appropriate for?

Comment: for something which is dynamic and needs a change in a running application